# TFS Parallel Builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have 1 build controller and 2 build agents. One build agent (tfsbuild01) is on the build controller machine (tfsbuild01). Another is on a separate machine (tfsbuild02).

We have 2 branches:

- Main
- 8.0

and 3 build definitions

- Main (Gated Checkin)
- 8.0 (Gated Checkin)
- Main Coded UI Tests (Scheduled for 12PM daily)

If someone queues up an 8.0 build and a Main build at the same time, the builds are correctly distributed across the two build agents and they build at the same time.

If the Coded UI Tests are running (which take an hour) and someone tries to check in to Main (which is Gated), the Main build sits in the queue until the Coded UI Tests finish. How can I get concurrent builds in the same branch working?

Tags configuration on all build definitions look like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you using tags on your agents? It sounds like you have "Main" and "tests" limited to run on the same tag, and only one of your agents is using that tag.

Comment: Do you have any tags on your build agents?

Comment: see screenshot. Not that I'm aware of. Also, we've seen the same behavior trying to process two gated checkins to main at the same time...it's like TFS only will build one branch at a time.

Comment: The screenshot is showing *one* of the build definition configurations *not* the agents' configurations. My current thinking is that you have one agent tagged, one untagged, and your 8.0 branch build is set to build on the tagged agent, while the other two builds are set to build on the untagged agent. The problem is one of build distribution -- it's running both builds on the same agent instead of distributing the latest build to an idle agent.

Comment: A follow-up question: Does the same problem occur if you queue a build off of the 8.0 branch while the tests are running?

Comment: No. 8.0 and Main builds have no problem running in parallel. Also I do see Main builds randomly distributed between tfsbuild01 and tfsbuild02, so I'm not sure it's an affinity problem. Is it possible it has to do with Gated Checkin not wanting to run more than 1 build at a time?

Comment: Is "Main Coded UI Tests" a different Build Definition?

Comment: Yes it is a different definition

Comment: Should I install a second build controller on tfsbuild02? Right now we have just 1 controller, 2 agents.

Comment: we have 3 build definitions

Main (Gated Checkin)
8.0 (Gated Checkin)
Main Coded UI Tests (Scheduled for 12PM daily)

Comment: You cannot have more than one Controller per server. BTW to be a gated check-in issue ("Each gated check-in build definition can have only one running build at a time" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx), you must have a common build def which is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a horses for courses question. You have your build of your asset and your instance tests mixxed up. I would recommend that you push your CodedUI tests off to an environment and only run the tests that can be executed from code, and ideally unit tests only, with no instance on the build box.

To execute your codedUI tests you should create a release pipleine in Release Management and also set up your release environment as a Lab environment. This way you can have quick builds and then ouch the longer validation out of that pipeline.

- http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/
- http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

This will free up your build agents and hopefully make your environment slicker.